# Making Http Request with Observables

Tags: angular

I have been trying to implement observables with my http request so i can make sure my component receives data before it progresses. This is what i have tried to do but i am not able to get the right process i want.
At the moment, the purchase assigned to the data in the lineChartArray remains empty because of the asynchronous nature of the request.

I want the component to wait to receive the data and assign to purchase.

Comment: `I want the component to wait to receive the data and assign to purchase.` <= what do you mean by this??

Comment: I am trying to explain that the component should hold up a while to receive the data before progressing. If not, the purchase in the lineArray is always null  because of the async nature

Comment: that's what the `.subscribe` is for. the first param in the `.subscribe` is invoked after the data is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to reassign `lineChartData` OR you have to grow/append to `purchase`.
2. You should use `OnInit` instead of executing the request  from the constructor.

Here is an example of how you reassign `lineChartData`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    Games : Games[] = [];
    purchase = [];
    public lineChartData:Array<any> = [];

    constructor(private httpService:HttpService){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpService.fetchPurchase()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.Games = data;
            this.purchase = data.map((v)=> v.confidence_level);
            this.lineChartData = [{data: this.purchase ,  label: 'Series A'}];
        });
    }
}
```